# Closed form solution to a linear program

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

For a given set of nonnegative weights $a_1, \ldots, a_K$, can we find the closed-form solution to the following optimization problem or the lowest computational complexity solution?

$\begin{equation}
\underset{  \{p_k > 0 \} }{\min} \quad \sum_{k=1}^K p_k a_k \quad s.t. \sum_{k=1}^K p_k = P_{max}
\end{equation}
$

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is $p_k$ required to be an integer?

Comment: No. They are positive real numbers.

Comment: Then you can get arbitrarily close to @daw's solution by taking some small $\epsilon > 0$, setting $p_k = P_\max - (K-1)\epsilon$ for the smallest $a_k$, and setting $p_k = \epsilon$ otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Set $p_k=P_\max$ for the index $k$ for which $a_k$ is minimal, set all other coefficients to zero.

Comment: Sorry. Every $p_k$ should be non-zero. I have edited the question.

Comment: Then there is no solution in general.